# How to segregate the li tag text under the collapsible button and also count number of li tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two collapsible buttons `Active Source` and `Inactive Source` and also have an array with some data in it.

**Now the problem statement:** I want to iterate through an array in such a way that all the `Active` text should come under the `Active Source` button and also all the `Inactive` text should come under `Inactive Source` button. Similarly count of entries under the respective collapsible should appear beside it.
If any of the text is not present in an array then "No active text present" OR "No Inactive text present" should appear under respective collapsible button.

**Note** :

- `Active Source` collapsible should be by default in a expand state as
  shown in fiddle.
- Text in an array should be there in `li` tag and `li` tag should get
  appended in `ul` tag

https://jsfiddle.net/hwc7qokf/

Comment: FIrstly, please include your code directly in your post. External links are not always available for future reference. Next, first thing I noticed in your code is that you have `a.map`, but aren't returning anything or saving this new array. Perhaps you want 'forEach()` instead.

Comment: @mykaf I tried with 'forEach()' also but can't come up with solution. If you can get the solution with 'forEach()' then you can proceed.

Comment: It should be identical, to your 'map` version, but `map` is meant to return something within the callback function, which is in turn used to populate an array.

Comment: @mykaf okay ,so is there a way with which we can iterate an array with 'forEach()' and get desired result.

Comment: You provided a *requirement* / *specification* of what you want, but not included (in the question) what you've attempted and more importantly, why it doesn't work - ie exactly what are you stuck on?

Comment: `.map` to `.forEach` literally just change "map" to "forEach": https://jsfiddle.net/Lru327s1/  If it's not working with .map then it won't magically work with .forEach - map is for returning an array, forEach is for iterating.  It's a semantic, not functional difference.

Comment: @freedomn-m how to segregate the data in array then , I am trying with if -else but didn't get the solution

Comment: @freedomn-m this was my requirement , in the process i could manage to do upto this and now stuck.

Comment: At the time of your `array.map(`, use `array.filter(...).map(` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter  Or a simple `if` inside the iteration to check the value.

Comment: Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/26k0me7j/